# NullReferenceExceptions in for/foreach loops

Tags: c#, xna

I'm working on building a little game, and I'm having an issue with reading a level map from a .txt file, converting it to a 2D array of characters, then converting any non blank character to an object of one type or another. I think converting to the 2D array is fine, but it looks like there's a null reference exception in one of two for loops traversing the array when converting to objects. Here's the code:

```
public void buildLevel()
{
    List<Tangible> objects = new List<Tangible>(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < map.GetLength(1); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < map.GetLength(0); j++)
        {
            if (map[j, i] == 'O')
            {
                objects.Add(new Ball((50 * j), (50 * i)));
            }
            if (map[j, i] == 'X')
            {
                objects.Add(new Block((50 * j), (50 * i), 50, 50));
            }
        }
    } 
    allObjects = objects;
}
```

Any idea what might be happening here? I really appreciate it.

EDIT: here's the code for reading the file into a 2D array:

```
public void setMap(String mapFile)
    {
        try
        {
            List<String> lines = new List<String>();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("maps\\testLevel.txt"))
            {
                String currentLine;
                while ((currentLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    lines.Add(currentLine);
                }
            }
            map = new char[lines[0].Length, lines.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < lines[0].Length; j++)
                {
                    map[j, i] = lines[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        catch (DirectoryNotFoundException e)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What line does the debugger put you on?

Comment: @Loren It puts me on

`for (int i = 0; i < map.GetLength(1); i++)`

Comment: Is your `map` object initialized?

Comment: @bytebuster now that you mention it, I think that might be the issue. A separate method is called to read in a file and convert it to the map array, and it may be that the file isn't being read in it's try/catch. I don't think I can fit it here, but I'll add it to the original post as an edit.

Comment: You may consider using `File.ReadAllLines` instead of using `StreamReader`. This will save few lines of code.

Comment: Your application should be starting in `<ProjectDir>\bin\Debug` directory. Are you sure the test file is located in `<ProjectDir>\bin\Debug\maps\testLevel.txt`? Can you place a breakpoint in `setMap` and check if it reaches the line populating the `map` variable?

Comment: Alright, it's working now! I had the wrong file path. Of course it would be the easiest and most obvious thing :/

Comment: This is not a question. The debugger already told you the answer and more, you just didn't look.